# Allow only defined plugin to install on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I would like to restrict plugins from the plugin install page. I can define the plugins that are allowed to be installed. For example, I need to stop the user to install a file manager plugin. When a user tries to install plugins that are not allowed, the install button could be disabled.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are giving full access ( Super Admin , Administrator ) then there is no way to restrict plugin installation .

Comment: @AnoopD Administrator role is not necessary. A custom user role also works. Thanks

Comment: You can use something like Members plugin for that . Hope that will solve your problem .